# Convention over configuration

Tags: gradle, ant, configuration, ivy, convention

I'm reading '***Building and testing with Gradle***' book, and it talks a little about  Ant and Apache Ivy having little conventions.

Can someone please provide an example of how Ant or Ivy does not provide convention over configuration compared with Gradle?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For instance, with either Maven or Gradle, if you store your source files in src/main/java and your tests in src/test/java and then just build it, using a very minimal build script, it just knows to compile everything, run the unit tests, and produce a jar of the compiled classes (from src/main/java).

With Ant, you have to tell it specifically where all of your source is, exactly what tasks are in play, and how to package everything up.

The point is, Maven and Gradle assume reasonable conventions and defaults, and just do it, without you having to specify it. If you're using Ant, there may be reasonable conventions about how you SHOULD set up your build script, but you still have to do that work.